# Is there a way to close a python window using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a test program to test out some things in python, and I can't seem to find a way to end the program and close the window in python.
this is my code:

```
yesorno = input('If you want to start the program, type yes, if not type 
no')
def cls(): print('hello')
cls()

if yesorno == 'y':
  del yesorno

elif yesorno == 'n':
  print("you chose wrongly.")
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: **import sys**
**import time** can help you on this

Comment: You can use  sys.exit() to terminate the program.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Comment: I tried that, and I got this error:AttributeError: '<invalid type>' object has no attribute 'exit' on line 4

Answer (score 0):

I commented to the solution but as you comment back that you are getting an error so here is the full solution :

First of all you have named any one of your file `sys` which is conflicting the local namespace and built-in namespace, since `sys` is built-in namespace but when you create your own file in IDE with the same name then python first try to lookup in `Local >> Enclosed >> Global >> Built-in` This is called `LEGB` rule.

Change your file name to something else and then try the code which i commented out:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```